# Elasticsearch NEST Boosting an existing query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We have a complex system for generating our elastic queries. We have objects like `QueryBuilder` that help us dynamically build our elastic query based on need. So our filtering is built using constructs like so: `AllFilters &= Query<TModel>.Must(requirement);`

Then when we build our query we do this, where `sd` is a `SearchDescriptor<TModel>`:

```
        var fullQuery = Query<TModel>.Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m
                .Bool(b2 => b2
                    .Must(Filter, OrFilter)
            )));

        sd = sd.Query(_ => fullQuery);
```

My question is, how do I correctly add boosting to this query?

I have a construct like `List<QueryContainer> AllBoosts`, which I enumerate like so:

```
    protected IEnumerable<QueryContainer> GetBoosts()
    {
        if (Boosts.OrEmptyIfNull().Any())
        {
            foreach(var boost in Boosts)
            {
                yield return Query<TModel>.Boosting(b => b.Boost(2).Positive(p => boost));
            }
        }
    }
```

And then try to `&=` it into the `SearchDescriptor`, but this returns no results:

```
        var fullQuery = Query<TModel>.Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m
                .Bool(b2 => b2
                    .Must(Filter, OrFilter) //these are filters we've built up with conditions in the code
            )));

        //here i enumerate boosts defined in the class
        foreach (var boost in GetBoosts())
            fullQuery &= boost; //should this be &=, |=, or something else?

        sd = sd.Query(_ => fullQuery);
```

Output query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [
    {
      "name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          //various must clauses from class properties / settings here
        },
        {
          "boosting": {
            "boost": 2.0,
            "positive": {
              "nested": {
                "query": {
                  "terms": {
                    "companies.id": [
                      "500086674"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "path": "companies"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to combine boosts into my query without changing the original build-up of the filters? Elastic version 5.4

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: elastic version 5.4

Comment: Is the query returning any errors? Have you run it in Kibana Dev Tools or curl?

Comment: yes there are some errors about negative boosting, i will look at fixing those and update quesiton if i can't figure it out

Comment: Are you wanting to boost _everything_ inside of the `bool` query?

Comment: I was doing this incorrectly, I added a boost do the single part of the filter that i need and it seems to be working